# Magento 2 get quote item taxes

Tags: magento2.2

Below function is not working in M2. This works in M1.

```
$quote=$observer->getEvent()->getQuote();
$taxes_for_items = $quote->getTaxesForItems();
```

Any alternate solution is available? I need quote item tax details.

Comment: Do you want to get tax amout whole or product vise?

Comment: Give proper declaration what do you want? because almost function are deprecated in magento 2.

Comment: Yes I need product wise tax data